# Dialog null after orientation change in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-configchanges

Each time I swipe there will be a new page loaded now I had everything working in portrait first and now I am trying to get it working with landscape and portrait. But when I rotate my screen I will get a `NullPointerException` on my `Dialog`.

The function causing it inside `MainActivity`'s innerclass `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` :

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentSelectedFragmentPosition = position;
        frag.onPageVisible(currentSelectedFragmentPosition);
            frag2.onPageVisible(currentSelectedFragmentPosition);
            frag3.onPageVisible(currentSelectedFragmentPosition);
    }
```

The function inside the fragment :

```
public void onPageVisible(int position)
{
     startNewAsyncTask();           
}
```

The dialog is instantiated inside the `onCreateView` and logs back that it is not null.
When I log inside `onPageVisible` it does log back null and when I do
`mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());` inside the `onPageVisible` it will still give a nullpointer but then on that line instead.

I really don't understand why it should be set in the `onCreateView`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `DialogFragment`, Android will re-create the dialog for you in `onCreate`. You can find the existing dialog by the tag in onCreate if your `savedInstanceState` is not null.

Comment: Ooh sorry I use ProgressDialog inside a AsyncTask.

Comment: Can I do something like `if(savedInstanceState != null) { mProgress = savedInstanceState.mProgress; }` ?

Comment: No if you are not using dialog fragments, you have to re-create the dialog yourself, if it was displayed when the activity was destroyed.

Comment: Like I said in the question I tried to recreate it but then it gives a nullpointer to that line

Comment: You need to post your stack trace.

Comment: I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to recreate your activity or fragment then just simply override onConfigurationChanged(){} method in your class which is extending Activity class.

This method will retain the state of your app whenever you change the orienation of your from to portrait to landscape or vice versa.

Comment: I don't really mind recreating as long as it works problem is that the dialog is set to null in the function or something.

Comment: I am not able to understand the last portion of your question buddy , are you trying to fetch data inside a Dialog Box?

Comment: The Dialog only displays that the AsyncTask is loading data. It works fine before the orientation change but after it will throw a NullPointerException so I'm searching a way to recreate it or get it back